# Asked for PhD grade in application but no grades awarded in my country

Tags: phd, funding, postdocs, united-kingdom, europe

I'm applying for a fellowship in continental Europe (Spain) and have been asked what grade I received. I think in many countries it's normal to receive grades over the course of a PhD, as well as an overall grade (of the form "with distinction", "cum laude" etc.) but this isn't common in the UK, where I received my PhD.

How should I answer the question? "N/A" seems most obvious, but should I explain in a footnote why I received no grade?

Comment: Who asked you? A human? A computer? How do you need to write the result?

Comment: Is it really common to get grades for PhD?

Comment: @kosmos US Ph.D students usually have to take courses so they would end up with a gpa, but the dissertation itself--no.

Comment: @kosmos In various European countries, yes, as listed e.g. on the German wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promotion_(Doktor)#Bewertung

Comment: @user111388 This is in a free-text form (page limit but no word limit).

Comment: @Rdd: Then just write that you did not get any grade by the UK system. Maybe add the email adress of some high guy in the program who can tell askers that you say the truth.

Answer (score 4):

In all questions like this the appropriate course of action is to **contact the people who run the application process** and ask.

They will be able to give you the appropriate instructions taking into account all the details we don't know. E.g. can you even leave it blank, is there an automated system, does it even matter for the ones that do have a grade etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I would just write ***not graded**.* This is short, accurate, complete, requires no footnote to explain, and I see no way this could be misinterpreted by a human or machine.